# Array of buttons returning null

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to add the buttons I create to an array and then remove them buttons from the array. My array keeps returning null so I get the feeling my buttons are not even being added to my array?

I am a beginner. I am using Xcode 4.3. Here is my code:

```
//
//  MainViewController.h
//  Test-Wards
//
//  Created by Dayle Pearson on 5/12/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> 
{
    /*This stuff creates a timer */
    IBOutlet UILabel *opponentsBlue;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int redBlue;

    /*Stuff for making a label creator */
    CGPoint startPoint;
    int xStuff, yStuff;

    /*array for storing wards*/
    NSMutableArray *wardArray;

}

@property CGPoint startPoint;

- (IBAction)startRedBlue:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)removeWard:(id)
sender;
- (void)countdown;

@end

//
//  MainViewController.m
//  Test-Wards
//
//  Created by Dayle Pearson on 5/12/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize startPoint;

- (void)countdown 
{
    if (redBlue < 2) {

        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    redBlue -= 1;
    opponentsBlue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", redBlue];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];
    startPoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.view];

}


- (IBAction)startRedBlue:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *wardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    wardButton.frame = CGRectMake((startPoint.x - 5), (startPoint.y - 5), 10, 10);
    [wardButton setTitle:@"180" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //add targets and actions
    /*[wardButton addTarget:self action:@selector() forControlEvents:<#(UIControlEvents)#>*/
    //add to a view
    [self.view addSubview:wardButton];

    [self->wardArray addObject: wardButton];
    NSLog(@"This elemnt = %@", wardArray);


}
- (IBAction)removeWard:(id)sender 
{
    [self->wardArray removeLastObject];    
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize your `wardArray`. You should add

```
wardArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

to your designated initializer.

In Objective-C sending messages to `nil` objects is legal - these messages are simply ignored. That's why you do not see the items that you added.

I also noticed that you add buttons to the view, but you never remove them. To remove the buttons from the screen, change the code as follows:

```
 - (IBAction)removeWard:(id)sender 
{
    [[self->wardArray lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    [self->wardArray removeLastObject];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your array before you can add to it

```
wardArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // quick and easy
wardArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // oldschool
```

I recommend doing it like so in your method. This will only initialize it once if it doesn't exist so theres no chance of it never being ready to have objects :)

```
- (IBAction)startRedBlue:(id)sender 
{
    ....

    // If wardArray doesn't exist we create it. Otherwise we add our ward to it.
    if (!wardArray) {
        wardArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    } else {
        [self->wardArray addObject: wardButton];
    }
}

- (IBAction)removeWard:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *ward = (UIButton *)sender;
    [ward removeFromSuperview]; // Takes it off the screen.
    [self->wardArray removeObject:ward]; //Takes it out of the array    
}
```

Comment: excellent it now adds and removes buttons from the array but it does not remove them from the screen?

Comment: You simply need to tell them to be removed from the screen. I've updated my answer with the removeWard method and added some code to it. I also altered it slighting so it won't just remove the last ward on the screen but the one you're actually touching.